# React Native MapView.Marker image crashes standalone Android App

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps with Expo SDK39
It was working fine with SDK38 but after upgrade it crashes when running as standalone app on android devices without any errors. It works fine inside the expo app.

This is a very weird issue, I just want to know what could cause this problem? My code is like this:

```
const markerIcon = require('../../assets/images/marker.png');
// ...
<Marker anchor={{x: 0.37, y: 1}} image={markerIcon} />
```

When I remove the image attribute it works fine. But with the image attribute, it crashes :(

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: I can confirm same thing. after removing `image` it works fine.

Comment: Just remove that image from "assetBundlePatterns" and it will work